# Apache not checking crl for revoked certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, certificate

I'm having an issue I can't really identify the cause of.

I set-up for testing purposes a local CA and a Webserver in a VirtualBox under Ubuntu.

I'm willing to try Client Certificate-Authentification.

I got it so far, that I can't access the webserver without having a valid certificate in my browser.

The problem is, that after revoking the Certificate, I still access the server.

In my default-ssl.conf (which is loaded) I have set :

```
SSLCARevocationFile to /etc/ssl/CA/crl/crl.pem
```

"crl.pem" was created using "openssl ca -gencrl /etc/ssl/CA/crl/crl.pem"

openssl crl -in /etc/ssl/CA/crl/crl.pem -text generates the following :

```
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
        Last Update: May 29 13:10:55 2014 GMT
        Next Update: Jun 28 13:10:55 2014 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 CRL Number: 
                4106
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: 01
        Revocation Date: May 29 10:35:53 2014 GMT
    Serial Number: 02
        Revocation Date: May 29 00:32:33 2014 GMT
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         4a:95:31:27:df:2b:d3:5f:91:86:32:18:7e:04:1f:88:99:22:
         2b:d6:03:8d:c6:1d:81:ca:06:a0:c3:c2:cf:fe:cb:8a:ec:f9:
         7f:bb:37:4c:69:70:1e:43:0c:8e:97:89:f7:32:f8:bf:9c:3b:
         fc:b2:25:55:98:a1:fe:7f:fb:ab:79:13:67:d6:75:02:c6:74:
         03:34:bc:f3:df:61:d5:0f:e6:1e:24:8b:e7:b0:17:1b:c4:2f:
         16:56:44:8d:e4:92:1f:48:51:23:a5:1d:54:26:a4:58:6b:4d:
         07:40:bb:48:7f:c1:61:00:55:20:d2:a1:56:f9:38:fa:f9:84:
         de:2a:a5:2a:69:82:d7:8b:35:24:5b:4d:ee:c0:33:7c:b6:d6:
         83:e2:f8:79:76:f9:04:55:80:45:8c:b1:9d:5b:8d:29:65:f9:
         6d:de:d3:d2:53:6e:f0:d2:44:c9:3e:60:ca:67:0f:2b:f9:27:
         0d:36:4b:90:d5:fe:7b:23:74:6b:94:e3:93:ea:4f:90:2b:db:
         c8:96:29:4b:cc:42:f6:31:27:e6:a2:ce:a3:c8:fa:47:74:bd:
         32:51:71:f3:66:fb:2d:76:0f:ca:64:23:55:eb:f8:5e:bc:0d:
         eb:f9:e4:7a:7f:72:be:fd:1a:a7:76:32:5e:0f:21:b9:c7:2a:
         89:ac:53:26
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----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-----END X509 CRL-----
```

I tried both certificates with the serial 01 and 02 and I'm able to login with both of them.

Does anybody has an idea what the problem may be ?

Thank you !

Comment: What browser are you using? Isn't it the browser's responsibility to check if the cert is revoked? After all, any attacker could simply configure their webserver to ignore the fact that their (stolen) cert is revoked -  so it makes not much sense for the webserver to ever check.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I'm trying Client Authentification (Sorry if I didn't make it clear). so shouldn't the server check if the certificate is revoked on the crl and then deny access if it is on it ?

Comment: Ah, yes I would definitely edit your question to include that. I believe your question is valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting the following Directive in your conf files (i.e. default-ssl.conf)

SSLCARevocationCheck chain

then stop and start your apache2 service and see the result.

Supawat P.

Comment: that was in fact the solution, I've done that a month ago but forgot to update the thread :) thank you anyways :)

Comment: Took my 8 hours to find this thread. Thank you for the answer, Supawat P.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to [gracefully reload server configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-2-reload-httpd-config-file-unix-linux-command/) after revoking the certificates and generating new CRL because it seems to be a [necessary step](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14104).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunatly this doesn't solve the problem. I tried to restart the apache Server and I generated a new crl everytime I revoked a certificate. when I verify the certificate with openssl I get the result that it is revoked.